# Why text does not show as I wrote it in xml?

Tags: android, xml, string, listview, checkbox

Why the text is not bold and italic as I wrote?
Here is my values string xml code:

```
 <string name="fragrance"> <b>FirstItem</b> \n<i>Description</i> </string>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to set it by this way:

```
Spanned htmlString = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.fragrance));
textView.setText(htmlString);
```

Comment: I have a class MyItem. It needs only String, I can't pass a html string to it. myitems.add(new MyItem(getString(R.string.fragrance),false));

Comment: Ok, you can store it as string value in MyItem, but you have to use it next as spanned to add it to textview.